# how to obtain an attribute value using attribute name as a string, like object["foo"]

Tags: c#

Can an object in C# return the value of one of its attributes if the name of the desired attribute is provided as a string at runtime?

```
myObject["price"]
```

Let's say we have this object:

```
public class Widget
{
     public Widget(){}
     public DateTime productionDate {get;set;}
     public decimal price {get;set;}
}
```

and this SqlCommand parameter definition:

```
 SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand();
 c.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@price", SqlDbType.SmallMoney,0,"price"));
```

Elsewhere in the code in a different scope, the user has clicked on a `[Save Record]` button and now we need to bind the values in a widget object to the parameters of an update command. We have a reference to that SqlCommand in variable `command`:

```
foreach (SqlParameter p in command.Parameters)
{     
     // assume `parameter.SourceColumn` matches the widget attribute name

     string attributeName = p.SourceColumn;

     p.Value = widget[attributeName]      // ??
  }
```

Comment: I think you mean "property", not attribute which has its own meaning in c#. And yes, you can use Reflection to get a Property value by name.

Comment: To access a property _exactly_ like you're referring to, you'd need some type of `Dictionary<string, object>` which lets you obtain a value through the key accessor `public TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition to Crowcoder:

You can use reflection and call Type.GetProperty("nameOfProperty") to get a PropertyInfo on which you can call the GetMethod property.

The GetMethod property returns a MethodInfo on which you can call the Invoke method to retrieve the value of the property.

For instance:

```
var propertyInfo = myObject.GetType().GetProperty("price");
var getMethod = propertyInfo.GetMethod;
string value = getMethod.Invoke(myObject, null) as string
```

Edit:

After reading your question again, I realise, I didn't answer your question.
You should/could combine my previous answer with an Indexer: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/index